# change Azure Data Explorer table folder when renaming multiple tables

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

When running the below command, I would like to change the folder of both tables.

**Command**

```
.rename tables Table1=Table2 ifexists, Table2=Table1
```

Prior to the rename command:

- Table1 is in a folder called F1
- Table2 is in a folder called F2

However, after the rename command is complete the table/folder combinations change like so:

- Table1 is in a folder called F2
- Table2 is in a folder called F1

I understand that I can change the folders after the fact (.alter table folder).  Is there a way to achieve the desired outcome without running extra commands?

For example:

```
.rename tables Table1=Table2 folder='F1' ifexists, Table2=Table1 folder='F2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's currently no single command that can perform all of those operations in a single transaction. if this feature is important to you, you can raise a feature request @ https://aka.ms/adx.ideas.

that said, what you can do is execute a sequence of commands using the [`.execute database script` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/execute-database-script).